# Wordpress - Homepage Index

Tags: wordpress, url, indexing, google-index

Need help.

The homepage and the navigation of the wordpress website I made have a different content once i search and click it from google index.

But once i directly open it thru address bar the orginal homepage and nav bar displayed.

What could be the problem here?

This one is when searched on google:
[image: This one is when searched on google]

This one is the correct one:
[image: This one is the correct one]

Comment: I think it's pretty clear that your site has been infected with malware. Install Wordfence or any other antivirus plugin, run a scan, and follow its instructions.

Comment: Also, this might help: [FAQ - My site has been hacked | WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked).

Comment: Hello @cabrerahector, but when I opened the wordpress editor and the pages.. i couldnt see that false content. So how is that possible?

Comment: Some malware detects when an admin is logged-in and thus they hide everything to avoid being detected. Regular visitors (non-logged in users) will definitely see this stuff (try yourself: visit your site using another browser or via Incognito mode). Again, install Wordfence and run a scan. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot. I installed wordfence and scanned the site but nothing showed up. @cabrerahector

Comment: Definitely sounds like  hack. Follow steps advised in https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked  and talk to your host, they may help you with the 'how' once they detect it.